# ionic cordova run android --prod not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

when I try to run my app in a device by using `--prod` command I get this Error:

[image]

ionic info:

```
C:\Users\INPT1\Desktop\ionic3\myApp>ionic info

cli packages: `(C:\Users\INPT1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)`

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

Global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

Local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.10.0
    npm  : 5.5.1
    OS   : Windows 8.1

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: please paste error message instead of image and add the relevant code.. read [mcve]

Comment: can you update your question with your app.module.ts code here? you seem to have some declaration error for your video.ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.)It shows that module is declaration of two parts so do as follow:

- -->Delete video.module.ts file from your page.
- -->Remove @IonicPage() from the video.ts file, also remove import {IonicPage}
- -->Do this for all pages and try running using --prod.

Comment: Thank you so much but why this issue didn't display when i use just `ionic cordova run android` and `ionic serve`

Comment: May be the due to running in production mode there will be conflict in copying files.