# Ionic 3 - Building prod app gives extra ngfactory and metadata files

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Have a quick question.

I'm building an app with Ionic, and when I ran

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

It generated a lot of new files inside my "src/pages"

[image: Screenshot of src/pages/home]

I'm just wondering if I should track these files in my Github, ignore them, or if there is any way to build in a different folder so I can keep my project files clean.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: which files are the generated ones? The files you will surely need are home.html, home.ts, home.js, home.scss

Comment: That doesn't look right at all. Those files shouldn't be there. Did you change anything in the webpack configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832145/ionic-cordova-run-android-prod-not-working/47842605#47842605

Comment: Yeah, it used to have only home.html, home.ts and home.scss before running the build prod, I didn't change anything in the webpack config, but I'm lazy loading pages fwiw. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while generating the build for release. Guess there is a bug somewhere when a specific error occurs, but I could remove these files safely without any issues and now my build is running without errors and won't generate all these files.