# Ionic 3 Angular 4 App throws error on prod release build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a Ionic 3 Application which works with Angular 4. It works well and it's nearing to release. When I ran the command, `ionic cordova build ios --prod --release`, it throws an error.

```
Type CompanyPortal in /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/pages/company-portal/company-portal.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule
            in /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/app/app.module.ts and CompanyPortalPageModule in
            /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/pages/company-portal/company-portal.module.ts! Please
            consider moving CompanyPortal in /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/pages/company-portal/company-portal.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in
            /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/app/app.module.ts and CompanyPortalPageModule in
            /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/pages/company-portal/company-portal.module.ts. You can
            also create a new NgModule that exports and includes CompanyPortal in /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/pages/company-portal/company-portal.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in
            /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/app/app.module.ts and CompanyPortalPageModule in
            /Users/ustuser/Documents/Proj/src/pages/company-portal/company-portal.module.ts.
```

Read through the forums and with the error log, removed the module specification from the page module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CompanyPortal } from './company-portal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //CompanyPortal,
  ],
  imports: [
    //IonicPageModule.forChild(CompanyPortal),
  ],
})
export class CompanyPortalPageModule {

}
```

After doing all such, another type of error occurs like

```
Can't bind to 'popUpListData' since it isn't a known property of 'cheader'. ("<ion-header class="top-bar">
            <cheader [ERROR ->][popUpListData]="changeDivisonData" [uName]="userName"
            [cheaderValue]="global.headerSelectedValue" (")
```

popUpListData is defined in one of my component class 'cheader'. The data is dynamic and it is mentioned here like   `@Input() popUpListData = [];`

These all works when using normal command `ionic cordova build ios` but fails on running for production.

Kindly suggest me the ideas to overcome from this.

Comment: Is CompanyPortal a lazy loaded page or a component? Is it an IonicPage?

Comment: It is a ionic Page and not a component.

Comment: can you add app.module.ts to your post?

Comment: refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832145/ionic-cordova-run-android-prod-not-working/47842605#47842605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Error in ionic build prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159788/page-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-error-in-ionic-build-prod)

Comment: Yes, did that and I got another issue which is mentioned above. Why a declared key cannot bind ? Can you provide any idea on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the issue with "ionic cordova build ios --prod --release" command, please use below command:

```
ionic cordova build ios --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs --release
```

[note:- "ionic cordova build ios --prod --release" command have email pattern 
matching issue in a form, always give invalid email error hence not used that 
command]
Use below link for more details:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/